# What are the different ways to call a function?

Tags: c

What are the different ways to call a function? For example, can I call a function without ()?

Comment: Doesn't doing this make you evil?

Comment: Is it only about C or also about C++?

Comment: Ask for C++ and there's about a gazillion ways to call a function without using (), using overloaded operators.

Answer (score 5):

You can call by name:

```
function_name(args);
```

You can call by function pointer:

```
void (*function_pointer)(int, char *) = ...;
(*function_pointer)(3, "moo");   // classic function pointer syntax
function_pointer(3, "moo");      // alternate syntax which obscures that it's using a function pointer
```

No, you cannot call a function without using `()`.  You can hide the `()` by using a macro but that just hides where they are; in the end you must use `()` somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a macro:

```
#define f func()
```

but this is not a recommended way. Your code will be very difficult to read and understand.

Comment: Yep, try declaring variable names `f` now :)

Comment: Thanks, you understand my question, great answer, but is not the idea that I wanted...thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

In C the `()` is *the function invocation* syntax. You cannot call a function without it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several pedantic ways to invoke a function without using (). Naming the function "main" (with correct parameter & return types) is one good way. You could register it as an interrupt handler. You could trick the compiler into jumping into it by smashing the stack (**not** portable and **not** recommended, works with gcc on 64-bit x86):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
        printf("In foo\n");
}

void bar()
{
        long long a;
        long long *b = &a;
        void (*fooptr)() = &foo;
        b[2] = (long long)fooptr;
}

int main()
{
  bar();
}
```

Comment: It's...perhaps best not to understand these dark magics. In any case, such techniques should be preceded with some basic assembler.